# In Visual Studio 2022, how to make the Debug window show the string variables as strings?

Tags: c++17, visual-studio-2022

I am using Windows 10 64 bit PC where I am running Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - version 17.6.4

Here I am trying to check a variable in Visual Studio debug window.
There is a string `project_repository_` which shows the string as character arrays. So, every time, for every string variable, I need to expand and check every character inside.

[image: visual studio 2022 debug window]

Where to find the setting to show string variables directly?

Comment: Is it a char array or std::string?

Comment: It's a std::string

Comment: Normally it would show it right under the `Value` heading where your image shows `{[size]=90}`.

Comment: Which window are you looking at? Autos? Locals? https://imgur.com/a/bRsfAnH

Comment: I checked both the windows, Autos, Locals. Both shows the same. I can now see the ```Value``` heading, however I can't see the strings, just the arrays

Comment: Do you have the “Show raw structure in debug windows” option enabled? That might be it

Comment: I wasn't aware of the "Show raw structure of objects in variables windows" option before. But I see that I can now see the whole string without enabling this option. I also see that, enabling that option brings up additional memory level information which are too detailed, which are not required to debug on different types of data I am working on. 

However, I appreciate having become aware of this option, as it could prove to be highly useful in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find the root cause of the problem, but the problem now does not exist after upgrading my PC to Windows 11 64 bit.

I can now see the whole string without expanding to every single character
[image]

I appreciate everyone's time and effort who tried to help resolve this issue.

Thanks guys!

Comment: _"I did not find the root cause of the problem"_ - so it wasn't the "Raw structure" setting then?

Comment: I am not too sure, but I guess it's not that setting problem